# E.Handled Not Work From TouchEventArgs in ShowDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got some trouble with stoping tunneling with Touch when a window was launched with ShowDialog().
My problem is : When I Touch the button in my Window, the clic(or touch ) continue to the MainWindow and open a new Window if antoher Button is behind.

I try to use

```
e.Handle = true;
```

To stop tunneling, it work if i clic with my mouse, but if i touch my screen it don't.

Here is a sample Of Code : ( This sample Window have just one button 'OK'. )

C#

```
public partial class MessageWindow : Window
{
.... other code ...
public static MessageBoxResult Show(string caption, MessageTypes type, MessageBoxButton buttons)
    {
        MessageWindow wnd = new MessageWindow();
        wnd.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
        wnd.Title = "Error Message";
        wnd.IsError = true;
        wnd.Message = caption;
        wnd.IsOk = true;
        wnd.ShowDialog();

        return wnd.Result;
    }

    private void OnOK()
    {
        Result = MessageBoxResult.OK;
        this.DialogResult = true;
    }

    private void _btOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        OnOK();
    }

    private void _btOKonly_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        OnOK();   
    }
.... other code again ....

}
```

XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Width="640" Height="480">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Background="Black" Padding="20,10">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Title, ElementName=Window}"/>
    </Border>
    <Button x:Name="_btOKonly" Content="OK" Click="_btOK_Click" TouchDown="_btOK_Click"Grid.Row="2"/>
    <StackPanel>
        < ... text of error ...>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Here is the code to launch my window :

C#

```
MessageWindow.Show(" This is a sample of error message", MessageWindow.MessageTypes.Error);
```

Thanks EveryOne Can Help Me :)

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I found my Answer.
In fact i have to just captur "Clic" and not the "Touch" action like this

```
<Button x:Name="_btOKonly" Content="OK" Click="_btOK_Click" Grid.Row="2"/>
```

And The "Clic" is Handle like it does.